# React-recompse - Initialize property only once

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recompose

I am `Reactjs` beginner and just started working on an existing `Reactjs` project that uses `react-recompose` module.

I am trying to declare a property and initialize it using `withProps`. The property initialization will use few other existing properties. I am passing this property to few child classes and these child classes will
modify this property multiple times by calling handlers from parent.
In the end, user will click on 'save' and the property state will be sent to server.
What is actually happening is after child classes call parent handlers which modify this property the `withProps` 
is getting invoked sometimes in between which reinitializes the property to it's initial state; Which results in recent changes to property being lost. Strangely, `withProps` isn't getting called every time the property is modified but only sometimes unpredictably.
 
I would like to know how can I define a property which is initialized as a product of few other properties; and
which is initialized only once when the page is loaded.
Please find sample code below.

```
const mapStateToProps = state  => ({
  user: state.users.user,
  allUsers: state.users.allUsers  
}); 



export function getRecentUsers(user, allUsers) {
    //Based on some criteria return some of the users from allUsers
    return recentUsers; 
}

export const Container = compose(
  connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps),
  withProps(({ user, allUsers, recentUsers}) => {
    return {
        recentUsers: getRecentUsers(user, allUsers)
    };
  }), 
  withHandlers({
    modifyRecentUsers: ({ recentUsers }) => (someUsers, myThis) => {
      //Modify recentUsers here
      myThis.setState({recentUsers : recentUsers});
    },
  ...
  ...
}(Users);

export const Users = ({
  user,
  allUsers,
  recentUsers,
  modifyRecentUsers
  }) => (
  <Child
    user={user}
    allUsers={allUsers}
    myThis={user.myThis}
    recentUsers={recentUsers}
    modifyRecentUsers={modifyRecentUsers}            
  />
 );

export class Child extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.user=this.props.user;
    this.allUsers=this.props.allUsers;
    this.myThis=this.props.myThis;
    this.recentUsers=this.props.recentUsers;
    this.modifyRecentUsers=this.props.modifyRecentUsers;    
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.recentUsers != undefined) {
      this.recentUsers = nextProps.recentUsers;
      this.setState({        
        recentUsers: nextProps.recentUsers
      });
    }
  }

  updateRecentUsers() {
    this.modifyRecentUsers(someUsers);
  }

     render() {
        return (
            //some html
        );
     }
 }
```

**EDIT**

In the example code I posted `recentUsers` is a property derived from `user` and `allUsers` and declared and initialized using `withProps`. `user` and `allUsers` are part of `redux` store. 
Even if either `user` or `allUsers` property changes I don't want `recentUsers` to be re-computed once it was initialized in `withProps`. Because, after initialization in `withProps`, I am updating `recentUsers` in response to application user actions, and any re-computation of it wipes out all these changes. Is it possible to initialize it only once?
 Also, changes to `user` or `allUsers` are only local. These changes are not written to the `redux` store until user clicks on 'Save'. Inside `withHandlers` I am doing something like `user.name = 'some name'`. I hope until these changes are written to `redux` store the `user` or `allUsers` updates should not result in re-initialization of `recentUsers` in `withProps`.

Answer (score 0):

`withProps` gives you *readonly* props that you generally compute from something. Your call to `myThis.setState` does not update that object. It's creating a key with the same name in your component's state.

With redux, state mutations belong to the reducers.

If `recentUsers` can be computed from `users` and `allUsers` and both are in redux, then your `withProps` is fine. It is your your `modifyRecentUsers` that is wrong. It should `dispatch` a `modifyUser` action. You `reducer` will then update the state (`users` and/or `allUsers`) and your component will re-render. That will trigger your `withProps` again, which will recompute `recentUsers` from `users` and `allUsers`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Sylvain. Based on your comments I have added additional details to my post under 'Edit' section.

Comment: And by mistake edited your post earlier instead of editing my question. Unable to undo it now -(